# how to implement kafka in golang using confuentic kafka library

Tags: go, golang-migrate

I have windows OS and i want to implement kafka in golang but after installing library it is showing error. whatever methods i am calling using kafka  it is undefined.For example methods like NewProducer, Configmap  etc are undefined. I am runing zookeer and kafka server using docker.

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
)

func main() {
    config := kafka.ConfigMap{"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"}
    producer, err := kafka.NewProducer(&config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to create producer: %v", err))
    }
    defer producer.Close()
    topic := "my_topic" // Replace "my_topic" with your actual topic name
p
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        message := fmt.Sprintf("Message %d", i)

        err := producer.Produce(&kafka.Message{
            TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
            Value:          []byte(message),
        }, nil)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to produce message: %v\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Produced message: %s\n", message)
        }
    }

    producer.Flush(15 * 1000)
}
```

Comment: Confluent's Kafka client relies on `librdkafka`, a C client library, for its operations. To utilize it on Windows, you'll need to install `librdkafka` alongside the Kafka client. [librdkafka](https://www.nuget.org/packages/librdkafka.redist/) here is the nuget link to install.

Comment: can you please tell me how to install it on windows, iam  new to golang,. and there is no helpful documentation which can help  me to install it

Comment: There is nothing related to Go on installation, you can basically use the link I have referenced in the comment above to install librdkafka then go client of the confluent should work properly.